# Mockito/Powermock class construction for generic class extension

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, mockito, powermockito

Not sure I worded the question correctly but I'm trying to mock the construction of a class that is being passed as a generic into the object I want to test.  Example below of what is taking place in the object I am testing:

```
MyClass(boolean historic, Class<? extends Learner> learner) {
    this.learner = learner.newInstance();
    this.historic = historic;
}
```

Learner is what I'm trying to mock and it is an interface for various learner classes I've built.  I'm not trying to test their logic here which is why I want to mock them and control what they return.  I'm trying to use the following setup (the static learner class has no constructor arguments):

```
@Test
@PrepareForTest({MyClass.class, Learner.class, StaticLearner.class})
public void test() {
    Learner mockLearner = Mockito.mock(StaticLearner.class);          
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Learner.class)
            .withNoArguments()
            .thenReturn(mockLearner);

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(true, StaticLearner.class);
    myClass.process();
}
```

Problem is Powermock is not able to construct the learner because it says no constructor can be found.  That makes sense since the Learner class is just an interface.  So how do I mock the StaticLearner being passed in and constructed when its simply a generic inheriting from Learner?

Here is the error I receive btw:

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.ConstructorNotFoundException: 
No constructor found in class 'com.myco.processing.learners.Learner' with parameter types: [ <none> ].
```

Comment: Why are you creating a `Learner` instance in the `MyClass` constructor at all? Why can't you just pass in a `Learner`? Then you could ditch PowerMock and just used the mocked instance.

Comment: Ha, that works.  Means I'll have to move the logic for determining which learner to use and construct 'further up the chain' but I'll cross that bridge when I get there.

Comment: @Markll Basically, never use PowerMock. If you find yourself wanting it, redesign your code.

Comment: Also not sure how to give you credit for that response.

Comment: It's fine, the points are fairly meaningless. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I use Powermock/Mockito all the time.  Can't agree with you on that statement.  Wonderful for singling out issues that can arise and rare edge cases that are tough to duplicate through other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `PowerMockito.whenNew(Learner.class)` with `PowerMockito.whenNew(StaticLearner.class)`. For example,

```
    @Test
    @PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})
    public void test() throws Exception {
        StaticLearner mockLearner = Mockito.mock(StaticLearner.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(StaticLearner.class)
                .withNoArguments()
                .thenReturn(mockLearner);

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(true, StaticLearner.class);
        myClass.process();
    }
```

#### Update

`PowerMockito.whenNew` works when `new` keyword is used, e.g, `new StaticLearner()`. It will not work if you use `StaticLearner.class.newInstance()`.

- If you want to mock `MyClass`, delegate the creation of `Learner` object to a new factory class, `LearnerFactory`.

  ```
  public class LearnerFactory {

      public static Learner getInstance(
          Class<? extends Learner> learner) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

          return learner.newInstance();
      }
  }

  public class MyClass {

      private boolean historic;

      private Learner learner;

      public MyClass(boolean historic,
          Class<? extends Learner> learner) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
          this.learner = LearnerFactory.getInstance(learner);
          this.historic = historic;
      }

      public void process() {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```
- Now mock the factory class to return the mock `StaticLearner`.

  ```
   @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
   @PrepareForTest({MyClass.class, LearnerFactory.class})
   public class MyClassTest {

       @Test
       public void test2() throws Exception {             
           StaticLearner mockLearner = 
               PowerMockito.mock(StaticLearner.class);
           //if needed
           when(mockLearner.doSomething(anyString()))
               .thenReturn("dummy");

           PowerMockito.mockStatic(LearnerFactory.class);
           when(LearnerFactory.getInstance(eq(StaticLearner.class)))
              .thenReturn(mockLearner);

           MyClass myClass = new MyClass(true, StaticLearner.class);
           myClass.process();
       }

   }
  ```

Comment: So I tried that.  That error vanishes however I get new errors because the class is not actually being mocked.  It is actually being created and called.

Comment: Somehow I need the `newInstance` method call to return the mocked learner class.

Answer (score 1):

Obvously the call to `learner.newInstance()` has no parameters. 
Even if id had they would be passed in as parameters to the constructor too.

So why don't you simply pass in the *result* of `learner.newInstance()` as parameter to this constructor? Then you could pass in a "regular" mock and you would not need <strike>PowerMock</strike>.

Comment: This is what was suggested in the comments above and what I went with.